# xmlns is appearing in places it shouldn't, and i'm not sure why

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to create an xml file through c# and I ran into a snag. I'm not sure why, my current code is adding an attribute of xmlns to each of the outer nodes. I only need it on the root node called Warehousereceipt.I tried to remove the namespace, but without it c# won't accept this file as a xml because it doesn't have the schema reference.

```
XNamespace xNamespace = "urlhere";
XElement newXML = new XElement(xNamespace + "WarehouseReceipt",
                    new XAttribute("Type", "WH"),
                    new XElement("Number", tempN[0]),
                    new XElement("ShipperName", tempS[0]),
                    new XElement("ConsigneeName", tempC[0]),
                    new XElement("Items",
                    from str in csv
                    let fields = str.Split(',')
                    select new XElement("Item",
                         new XAttribute("Type", "WI"),
                         new XElement("Satus", fields[3]),
                         new XElement("Pieces", fields[6]),
                         new XElement("Description", fields[5]),
                         new XElement("PackageName", fields[4]),
                         new XElement("Length",
                             new XAttribute("Unit", "in"), fields[7]),
                         new XElement("Volume",
                             new XAttribute("Unit", "ft3"), fields[11]),
                         new XElement("Height",
                             new XAttribute("Unit", "in"), fields[8]),
                         new XElement("Width",
                             new XAttribute("Unit", "in"), fields[9]),
                         new XElement("Weight",
                             new XAttribute("Unit", "lb"), fields[10]),
                         new XElement("WarehouseReceiptNumber", fields[0])
                     )
                    ),
                    new XElement("MeasurementUnits",
                        new XElement("LengthUnit", "in"),
                        new XElement("VolumeUnit", "ft3"),
                        new XElement("WeightUnit", "lb")
                   )
              );
            return newXML;XElement newXML = new XElement(xNamespace + "WarehouseReceipt",
                    new XAttribute("Type", "WH"),
                    new XElement("Number", tempN[0]),
                    new XElement("ShipperName", tempS[0]),
                    new XElement("ConsigneeName", tempC[0]),
                    new XElement("Items",
                    from str in csv
                    let fields = str.Split(',')
                    select new XElement("Item",
                         new XAttribute("Type", "WI"),
                         new XElement("Satus", fields[3]),
                         new XElement("Pieces", fields[6]),
                         new XElement("Description", fields[5]),
                         new XElement("PackageName", fields[4]),
                         new XElement("Length",
                             new XAttribute("Unit", "in"), fields[7]),
                         new XElement("Volume",
                             new XAttribute("Unit", "ft3"), fields[11]),
                         new XElement("Height",
                             new XAttribute("Unit", "in"), fields[8]),
                         new XElement("Width",
                             new XAttribute("Unit", "in"), fields[9]),
                         new XElement("Weight",
                             new XAttribute("Unit", "lb"), fields[10]),
                         new XElement("WarehouseReceiptNumber", fields[0])
                     )
                    ),
                    new XElement("MeasurementUnits",
                        new XElement("LengthUnit", "in"),
                        new XElement("VolumeUnit", "ft3"),
                        new XElement("WeightUnit", "lb")
                   )
              );
            return newXML;
```

here is the current output so you can see what i mean. PS: the way the xml file is organized is exactly how i need it, so please don't suggest changing things around the structure.

```
<WarehouseReceipt Type="WH" xmlns="urlhere">
  <Number xmlns="">"3519"</Number>
  <ShipperName xmlns=""> "4 NET NETWORKING CORP"</ShipperName>
  <ConsigneeName xmlns=""> "ACUAMAR"</ConsigneeName>
  <Items xmlns="">
    <Item Type="WI">
      <Satus> "On Hand"</Satus>
      <Pieces> "10"</Pieces>
      <Description> "APPLE NEW IPAD"</Description>
      <PackageName> "Case"</PackageName>
      <Length Unit="in"> "5.00"</Length>
      <Volume Unit="ft3"> "0.60"</Volume>
      <Height Unit="in"> "5.00"</Height>
      <Width Unit="in"> "4.00"</Width>
      <Weight Unit="lb"> "10.00"</Weight>
      <WarehouseReceiptNumber>"3519"</WarehouseReceiptNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item Type="WI">
      <Satus> "On Hand"</Satus>
      <Pieces> "20"</Pieces>
      <Description> "APPLE IMAC "</Description>
      <PackageName> "Box"</PackageName>
      <Length Unit="in"> "35.00"</Length>
      <Volume Unit="ft3"> "273.40"</Volume>
      <Height Unit="in"> "45.00"</Height>
      <Width Unit="in"> "15.00"</Width>
      <Weight Unit="lb"> "400.00"</Weight>
      <WarehouseReceiptNumber>"3519"</WarehouseReceiptNumber>
    </Item>
  </Items>
  <MeasurementUnits xmlns="">
    <LengthUnit>in</LengthUnit>
    <VolumeUnit>ft3</VolumeUnit>
    <WeightUnit>lb</WeightUnit>
  </MeasurementUnits>
</WarehouseReceipt>
```

Comment: If you don't tell the language what namespace an element is it has to move it back to the unspecified one. You're better off caching the `XNamespace` and then adding it to the names below ex: `XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com"; ` and `new XElement(aw + "Root");` this applies to _all_ child elements btw in that namespace

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your reply. My apologies, i didn't realize i didn't include in my question that one line where i define it. I added it now. You say that doing that applies it to all child elements in the namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See docs: [How to control namespace prefixes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/control-namespace-prefixes).

```
XNamespace xNamespace = "urlhere";

XElement newXML = new XElement(xNamespace + "WarehouseReceipt",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "prefix", "urlhere"),
    new XAttribute("Type", "WH"),
    new XElement("Number", 1),
    new XElement("ShipperName", 2),
    new XElement("ConsigneeName", 3),
    //...
    );
```

Result:

```
<prefix:WarehouseReceipt xmlns:prefix="urlhere" Type="WH">
  <Number>1</Number>
  <ShipperName>2</ShipperName>
  <ConsigneeName>3</ConsigneeName>
  ...
</prefix:WarehouseReceipt>
```